# How to hide (Child samplers ) in jtl and html report

Tags: jmeter, performance, performance-testing, loadrunner

Executed the test in Non GUI mode and  jtl file child samplers are also got generated and after reading the articles tried to uncheck the Save the subresults and clicked on done but still child samplers are visible.
[image]

[image]

Could anyone please help me

Answer (score 2):

1. If you don't want to see child sample results in the .jtl results file - you can set `jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults` property to `false`
2. If you don't want to see child sample results in the HTML Reporting Dashboard you can filter them out via `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` property, the expression would be something like `^((?!-).)*(-success|-failure)?$`

More information:

- [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Reporting Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

However I believe you should rather:

1. Apply the naming policy for your transactions:

   [image]
2. And export them for reporting:

   [image]

This way JMeter will automatically treat the sub-results as a part of the transaction:

[image]