# How to hide(child samplers) in jtl and html report using jmeter tool

Tags: jmeter, performance, performance-testing, loadrunner

After making changes in JMeter but still I can able to child samplers. I have followed this link [How to hide (Child samplers ) in jtl and html report](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/51860/how-to-hide-child-samplers-in-jtl-and-html-report/51861#51861)

Below are the changes I made in JMeter:

1. Unchecked the save the result option.
   [image]
2. Export transaction results are like below.
   [image]
3. Also added the **Jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false** manually in user.properties file
   [image]

Could anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

1. [You should not be using any listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean), they don't add any value and just consume valuable resources.
2. Yes, you are very smart and generated the proper export filter but I fail to see where the filter is applied, you need to define it as a JMeter Property either in [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) or pass it via [`-J` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
3. Remove `#` sign from the beginning of the string, it means that the line is commented out. Also add a new line with the generated `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` property value

Once done you can [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) as:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -f -l /path/to/result.jtl -e -o /path/to/dashboard
```

and you shouldn't see "child" samplers anymore (if it's really what you're looking for)

Comment: Thanks Drimiti for answering my all questions and you are very knowledgeable person.  It worked for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers